# Accessing cookies from a chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I can see that when I issue an xhr from my chrome app that it sends some cookies, and these cookies are kept track of in the app.  Servers sending set-cookie headers are updating them correctly.  I need to read a cookie though, and I tried using the "cookies" permission but chrome yelled at me...    Is there another api I can use?

edit: I am using the new packaged apps.

Comment: Some cookies are [http-only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly). For such, there should NOT be a way to get them via JavaScript.

Comment: I strongly disagree. I should not have to implement the HTTP request using sockets just to get the returned header I need (set-cookie)

Comment: In any case im not trying to get an http only cookie

Comment: Is your question related to the new Packaged Apps?

Comment: Yes it is.  Did I use the wrong tag, or should I use another as well?

Comment: I'm almost sure this is not possible, because the document.cookie API is disabled in a packaged app. But I won't send an answer because there might be some creative/convoluted way using sandboxed iframes that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is there any way to get the chrome team to reconsider giving packaged apps the cookies permission that extensions currently have?

Comment: Yes, post a bug at http://crbug.com/new and clearly explain why you need it (your use case and why this is the only way you can achieve the required results)

Comment: Thank you, I've created this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236585

Answer (score 4):

Cookies is apparently a dark area of Chrome Packaged Apps.

With Extensions, the extension shares the cookie jar with normal browsing activities. For Packaged Apps, each app has a separate jar.

The current behaviour seems to be that XHR requests to sites specified in the manifest in the permissions section do set cookies in this jar but there is no way how to get rid of them, except reinstalling the app. There is no API for Packaged Apps to manage cookies and their cookies do not show in Developer tools or about://settings/cookies page.

the crbugs include

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70391
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152758
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157474

and these two issues filled in response to this SO question

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236585
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335934

Comment: I noticed there are some [optional_permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permissions) that also include cookies, anyone tried with those permissions to access/erase cookies?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where security restrictions on XHR in a packaged app with chrome.socket api permission seemed overbearing. See [Setting "unsafe" headers in packaged app XHR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105471/setting-unsafe-headers-in-packaged-app-xhr)

I ended up creating a "shim" xhr object for my use case, though it doesn't handle e.g. chunked encoding. You might find it useful: https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent/blob/fresh/js/chromesocketxhr.js

I ended up filing a bug on crbug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335934

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added some comments to the issue.  Hopefully they fix this so that we don't have to actually re-implement xhr over sockets.