# Setting "unsafe" headers in packaged app XHR

Tags: google-chrome-app

I need to modify the User-Agent header in an XHR request in my packaged app. When I do so, I get the error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

My app already has full socket access, so I could do it that way. But that would be really, really annoying.

It would be super nice if I were allowed to set this header in packaged apps that already have raw socket access.

Maybe there is some other API or permission that I'm not aware of? webRequest doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: I ended up coding a "fake" XHR object using chrome.socket. This means it won't work for HTTPS, as there's still no TLS api for chrome.socket. It's not very general purpose, but you can find it here if you want to base something off it https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent/blob/fresh/js/chromesocketxhr.js

Comment: I agree it's annoying, but you do get XHR for free in terms of permission prompts ("Has no special permissions"), so there is a tradeoff from the user's point of view. Allowing a non-Chrome-standard XHR in a Chrome App would probably require a special kind of permission prompt similar to the socket API prompt, and that's getting into a complicated area of UX that's probably good for nobody.

Comment: I forgot that chrome.socket permissions were very granular and specific to hosts, so perhaps adding code to chrome to bypass the "unsafe header" checks when these permissions are granted would add perhaps a little too much complexity. Still, it would be cool if this were done; and I don't think it would need to change any existing UX if done in this way.

Comment: I see your point, but I'd need to think it through some more. So that we don't forget, will you please file an issue at crbug.com/new and assign it to me (miket at chromium)?

Comment: Filed at crbug - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335934

Comment: Thanks. I forgot you can't set owners. I'll have a look when I get back in the office.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that this will be addressed on the Chrome platform. So when I need to have more control over my XMLHttpRequest, I use my own shim, which I am keeping up to date inside the [Web Server for Chrome (github)](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) project. You can see it being used in this [example](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome/blob/c1b300256ade44e3746e521b2197d4c612533fcd/handlers.js#L40)