# How do I modify User-Agent in Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-app, user-agent

How can I change User-Agent in a Chrome App for all my XHR requests?

I see that `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` APIs are not available to "Chrome Packaged Apps".

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Have you looked through this one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105471/setting-unsafe-headers-in-packaged-app-xhr

Comment: Yes, I visited the question. It is not answered yet and the comments didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [WebRequestEventInterface](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInterface) which provides access to webRequest events on the guest page of Chrome App.

Also possible to use [setUserAgentOverride](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride) of webview. [Example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/user-agent). (More real way to modify UA)

**How to use:**

[Create webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) in your App. Load JS for XHR in webview as in iframe. Use [WebRequestEventInterface](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInterface) and [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) events for modify HTTP(S) headers (possible [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105471/setting-unsafe-headers-in-packaged-app-xhr)) or use [setUserAgentOverride](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride) before XHR requests for modify UA (the easiest way).

Comment: That affects `<webview>`, but the question is about XHR.

Comment: Question is about workarounds to modify UA for XHR requests :) <webview> is similar to <iframe>

Comment: Well, it requires more explanation how to use that for, say, cross-origin XHR with special permissions (if that's at all possible).

Comment: webRequestEventInterface stable for webRequest.  Dev channel for devdeclarativeWebRequest.

Comment: No problems with permissions for own JS.

Comment: Oh, in that case it's a case of bad documentation w.r.t. webRequest. I retract my objection. But I'll probably file an issue to adapt the docs somehow to it.

Comment: webRequestEventInterface since Chrome 33. Maybe Chrome add in API something new.